# Divs with Same Class Name: Select First Child and Set Different CSS Styles for Each

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm creating a slideshow and I use JS to set the position of the controls. To do that, I get the height and width of the first image to make the calculation.

HTML:

```
<div class="slideshow">
          <figure class="image">
            <img src="images/or-staff.jpg" />
            <figcaption>Insert caption</figcaption>
          </figure>
          <figure class="image">
            <img src="images/patient-phone.jpg" />
            <figcaption>Insert caption</figcaption>
          </figure>
           <figure class="image">
            <img src="images/labor-nurse.jpg" />
            <figcaption>This is an example of a really long caption. Here I go. Do I wrap to a second line? Wrap wrap wrap wrap. Wrap Wrap Wrap Wrap Wrap Wrap Wrap Wrap Wrap Wrap Wrap</figcaption>
          </figure>
        </div>
```

JS:

```
  var imageHeight = $(".slideshow img").first().height();
  var imageWidth = $(".slideshow img").first().width();
```

Based on the calculation, I add some CSS to the slideshow div to position the controls.

However, if I have more the one slideshow on the page, both with a class of "slideshow", then the image width and height are only taken from the first image in the first slideshow.

How do I cycle through the slideshows, get the image height and width of the first image for each, and then set the position of the controls separately for each?

I tried doing something like this to get the height of each, but it returned null:

```
$(".slideshow").each(function() {
    var imageHeight = $(this).find('.slideshow-inner:first-child').outerHeight();
    console.log(imageHeight);
    });
```

Comment: Use `.slideshow .image:first-child {}`

Comment: @TylerH I don't think you're understanding the question correctly.

Comment: @Pointy It depends on what OP means by "separately for each".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through the "slideshow" containers:

```
$(".slideshow").each(function() {
  var container = this;
  var imageHeight = $(container).find("img").first().height();
  var imageWidth = $(container).find("img").first().width();
  // ... do stuff ...
});
```

Inside the `.each()` callback, `this` will be the container DOM element.

Comment: That worked. Thank you. Now I need to divide the height by the width, turn it into a percentage, and it to a class within that specific div. So, let's say that the result is 65%. How would I add that 65% to the slideshow div that is currently being cycled through? Here is what I used before: $(".previous").css("paddingBottom", percent);
 I somehow need to say, "select the previous class for this specific slideshow." Can I select both the variable of container and the class of previous?

Comment: I think I got it: $(container).find(".previous").css("paddingBottom", percent);. It seems to work. Thanks!